# Unable to add values to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

I am trying to find the MACD(Moving Average Convergence Divergence) for a few stocks.I am using Pandas_ta, yfinance and pandas libraries. But When I am trying to add the Macd values to the dataframe I am getting this error:

```
IndexError: iloc cannot enlarge its target object
```

My code is :

```
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_ta as ta
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
start=dt.datetime.today()-dt.timedelta(365)
end=dt.datetime.today()
zscore=pd.DataFrame()
rsi=pd.DataFrame()
tickers=['2060.SR' , '2160.SR', '3002.SR', '4007.SR', '3005.SR', '3004.SR' , '2150.SR']
macd=pd.DataFrame()
for i in tickers:
  df=pd.DataFrame(yf.download(i, start=start, end=end, interval="1mo"))

  df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)    
  macd=df.ta.macd()
```

Can someone let me know where my mistake is and how to solve this error. thanks

Comment: Which line gave this error?

Comment: macd=df.ta.macd()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df=df.merge(macd, on="Date")

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which line gave you this error.

But please note that in the loop you are not adding data, but you are re-writing the data again and again:

```
for i in tickers:
  df=pd.DataFrame(yf.download(i, start=start, end=end, interval="1mo"))
```

If you want to append, do the following:

```
agg_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in tickers:
  df=pd.DataFrame(yf.download(i, start=start, end=end, interval="1mo"))
  agg_df = agg_df.append(df)
```

Comment: I tried this but i am getting the same error.The error is in line macd=df.ta.macd()

Comment: I am not familiar with the macd() function. But try also: macd = df['ta'].macd()

Answer (score 0):

I used `df.append(row)` in the past which is deprecated since pandas 1.4.
most logical for me is the approach:
`df.loc[len(df)] = ['list', 'of', 'elements']   # len(df.columns)`

other methods are provided here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/how-to-append-row-to-pandas-dataframe/